# NFS symbolic link to /root possible?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, nfs

Suppose that I have access to nfs server. The directory that I have an access is /shared and it is owned by root. I can read and write to that directory + subdirectories + files. Suppose that I want to make a symbolic link to /root at the server (not the client's root directory, but server's.). Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can create the symlink, but it will point to the local `/root` on whichever host the NFS share is mounted.